# How to ingore rpmfusion source repos when downloading source package

Tags: fedora, rpm, repository, source, dnf

I have few rpm repos in my Fedora installation and I've want to download source package and got error that synchronization of `rpmfusion-free-updates-source` and `rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-source` failed. they probably don't have source.

I've executed this command, that returned error:

```
sudo dnf download --source hicolor-icon-theme
```

is it possible to ignore repo, without disabled it for just one command? The download was successful but I want to know if something like this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore a repository:

```
dnf --disablerepo=<repoid> ...
```

This enables disabling a repository for a single command. Similarly, one can use `--enablerepo=<repoid>` to dynamically add a repository to your standard configuration for the command being run.

You can stack a list or repositories to skip, too, with (for example):

```
dnf --disablerepo=fedora-modular,updates-modular ...
```

Comment: Yes but, isn't `--disablerepo` disabling repo from whole system? Or is it just for single command?

Comment: It seems that this don't work and my question also was wrong because the issue is to to disable repo but something with cache, my exact error is `Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'rpmfusion-free-updates-source', ignoring this repo.` this command don't solve the issue `sudo dnf --disablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates-source,rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-source  download --source hicolor-icon-theme`

Comment: Please try `dnf clean all` and then, `dnf --disablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates-source,rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-source repolist`.  You should not see the `rpmfusion` repo-ids in the output list.

Comment: Re-reading your last comment: if you *do* want the repositories enabled but are getting a synchronization error, try `dnf clean all` before your download (without disabling anything).  Generally, synchronization errors point to an inability to reach a repository (e.g. not connected to a network, etc.).

Comment: Marking as solved since this is in fact was correct answer to my question. `dnf clean all` didn't solved synch issue, I think it just removed downloaded files.